# How to validate transaction receipt in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i completed in app purchase in flutter and it works well.but i want to verify receipt with Appstore but i am getting brackets end of the receipt like **EBBIIBZzGCAWMwCwICBq0CAQEEAgwA<…>** 
this give me error
 i am using flutter in [flutter_inapp_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase) package

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the guidelines on how to ask a question. This will improve your odds of getting quality answers to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask